# HTML sanitization WebApi EntityFramework application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, xss, asp.net-web-api2, modelstate

I have found a somewhat good documentation on HTML sanitization in MVC and Razor views. However, I want to protect my WebAPI2 project from XSS attacks by sanitizing un-safe html text.

The application has sections for entering HTML templates for email messages, which I need to allow style related HTML, but strip dangerous html. Is there a tool or way to annotate a model property that will detect these things and return a bad model state? Something like -

```
public class MyDTO 
{
    [Required]
    [SanitizeXSS]
    public string Subject {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [SanitizeXSS] 
    public string Body {get;set;}

}
```

I am using Angular on the client side and using some form validation. However, since the endpoints are exposed via WebAPI, I would like to augment this with some server side sanitization. Are there any libraries/built in methods that do this, or will have I have to roll my own attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no automatic attribute available for this, you'll have to do some work yourself.

I'm not sure if you already know about the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](https://wpl.codeplex.com/). It includes the **AntiXSS** component ([NuGet link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXss/)), which seems ideal for what you want. [This OWASP article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library) contains a lot of useful information and Haacked has a [tutorial on how to use it](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx/).

However, be aware that there are problems with it and [this article](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/) attempts to address/work around some of them.

*Note:* I've personally not used it so I can't comment from experience.

Comment: Adding this as the answer, although it must be stated that it seems all the .NET solutions for this are quite lacking. I ended up using [this](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/) article, but it seems there should be a better out of the box experience for this with ASP.net